# Creating and loading custom pipeline in Spacy

Tags: nlp, pipeline, spacy

I need to run a NLP pipeline on multi-page documents. A text classifier operates on the first N sentences and based on the text classifier output, new custom elements need to be added to the pipeline. I could of course restart the pipeline with the new elements but it would require to re-run again everything from the start (tokenizer, sentenizer, and more).

Is it possible to capture the state of the pipeline (e.g. the doc object), modify the pipeline, and continue where it was left of with the new pipeline and its new elements?

What is the recommended way for such scenarios?

Thank you

Comment: If you are looking for a resource to try [Processing Pipeline using Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines), Also  refer to this [Release](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/releases/tag/v2.1.0a1)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can create a pipeline without a tokenizer or stop/start in the middle of a pipeline, but because all the non-tokenizer components take and modify a `Doc`, you can load a pipeline with all the components you might use and then call each component as needed:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en')
# nlp.make_doc() is equivalent to nlp.tokenizer()
doc = nlp.make_doc("This is a sentence.")
# there are shortcuts for default model components
nlp.tagger(doc)
nlp.parser(doc)
nlp.ner(doc)
# but you can access any component with nlp.get_pipe(), also "tagger", etc.
nlp.get_pipe("your_component_name")(doc)
nlp.get_pipe("tagger")(doc)
```

The API doesn't prevent you from trying, but you don't want to apply components that were loaded as part of a different pipeline than the one used to create the `Doc`, because you can run into problems when the `Doc` and the component don't share the same `vocab`.